# Center image in Bootstrap 3 on a HTC wider and taller screen

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image that will not align center. I'm sure I'm doing something drastically wrong. How can I center this image? Ive tried styles, margin auto, center-block, center-text etc. Nothing works.

On all small mobile devices the 320px image is centered and full width, however those larger mobile devices (Wider iPhones, HTC, GalaxyS5 etc) - are left aligned.

```html
<header id="about2" class="about-mobile visible-xs hidden-sm" style="background-color:#20aab4; margin-top:0;height:661px;">
  <div class="text-vertical-center" style="margin-top:0;">
    <div class="visible-xs " style="z-index:1;">
      <div id="num10" class="visible-xs">
        <BR>
        <BR>
        <img src="images/homepage/INTROs_AboutUs_Mobile.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" width="320" height="661" usemap="#MapAboutUs" />
        <map name="MapAboutUs">
          <area shape="rect" coords="66,237,147,270" href="our-story/index.html">
          <area shape="rect" coords="153,239,257,267" href="our-navigators/index.html">
        </map>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/fi17xpjfx/

Answer (score 0):

the width="320" height="661" in your  hard defines the width and height of the image.  On smaller screens that have a width of 320.  The width="320" matches the 320px width so it fills the width but for obvious reasons with larger screens it will now.  This is why you no longer want to use inline styling and defined width and height for  tags and put everything into a separate .CSS file.  Try doing the same thing with...

```
   img {width:100%;height:auto}
```

This will take the width of the parent element  tag. Then adjusting the height appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it does not work. Can you tell me specifically where to add that? If I do it at the top level- all images want to be 100% width. Also- I want the image centered, doesnt have to be stretched 100% width.

Comment: remove width="320" height="661" in your <img> tag. Your 'center-block' class is just a class that defines it as display:block and gives it an auto left right margin.  So if it is not centered after removing the width and height inspect the elemeent using your browser and check the margins for left and right are the same.  If they are not then something is overriding them.